# Find grandchildren with specific tag

Tags: unity

I have an empty object that contains multiple children each containing their own child objects. I want to get a list of all the objects containing a specific tag but i don't know the depth of each child object. 
The following solution only returns the children that have the tag.

```
foreach (Transform child in city)
        {
            if (child.CompareTag("Zone"))
                buildings.Add(child);
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: When the objects you want to find also happen to have some component in common, then you could use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
public List<GameObject> GetChildrenWithTag(GameObject obj)
{
    var childrenWithTag = new List<GameObject>();
    var allChildren = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    foreach(var child in allChildren)
    {
        if(child.gameObject.CompareTag("Zone"))
        {
            childrenWithTag.Add(child.gameObject);
        }
    }
    return childrenWithTag;
}
```

I didn't test this code but I guess it works. You may also want to avoid to hard-code tags like you did with "Zone".